# Adding pagination to the following text:

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, pagination

I have pagination on my users table at the moment which works fine as I only have one search feature for users.

But I now wish to add pagination to my games table but not sure how to implement it as I have 5 search features for games. I was wondering how I would go about adding the pagination to the following controller method.

```
    def index
        @games = Game.gamsearch(params[:gamsearch])
        @games = Game.consearch(params[:consearch]) if params[:consearch].present?
        @games = Game.gensearch(params[:gensearch]) if params[:gensearch].present?
        @games = Game.where("game_name LIKE ?", "#{params[:game_name]}%") if params[:game_name].present?
        @games = Game.where("console = ?", params[:console]) if params[:console].present?

    end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use scopes or methods that return ActiveRecord relation in your Game class and chain them (I guess you want to combine condidtions by AND operator):

```
class Games
  scope gamsearch, lambda { |search_param| your_conditions }
  scope consearch, lambda { |search_param| your_conditions }
  scope gensearch, lambda { |search_param| your_conditions }
  scope game_name, lambda { |game_name_param| where("game_name LIKE ?", "#{game_name_param}%") }
  scope console, lambda { |console_param| where("console = ?", console_param) }
end


def index
  scope = Game.gamsearch(params[:gamsearch])
  scope = scope.consearch(params[:consearch]) if params[:consearch].present?
  scope = scope.gensearch(params[:gensearch]) if params[:gensearch].present?
  scope = scope.game_name(params[:game_name]) if params[:game_name].present?
  scope = scope.console(params[:console]) if params[:console].present?
  @games = scope.paginate
end
```

Comment: I tried using scope but kept getting undefined method paginate despite it already being defined.